# Script runs extremely slow, needs to be more efficient

Tags: javascript, performance, photoshop, software-design

**Goal:**

My script takes every folder and layer in photoshop, gets the center point coordinates, and saves them to a txt file.

**Issue:**

The script works very well and gives the exact data I need. However, the script runs extremely slow when I have lots of photoshop layers. For example I ran the script on a PSD that has lets say 200 small layers. This took about 20 minutes to get the output text file that I need. MY question, and bare in mind I am not a programmer, is how to increase the efficiency of this code, and have this run faster.

**Here is a Sample of the Output Data:**

1 -MUD ROOM/GARAGE: 483.5x,559y

130A: 307.5x,681y

Lighting_icon_square_4x copy 19: 382x,749y

Lighting_icon_square_4x copy 19: 382x,681y

Lighting_icon_square_4x copy 19: 382x,613y

Lighting_icon_square_4x copy 18: 233x,749y

Lighting_icon_square_4x copy 17: 233x,681y

Lighting_icon_square_4x copy 13: 233x,613y

**The Code:**

```js
// Bring application forward
app.bringToFront();

// Set active Document variable and decode name for output
var docRef = app.activeDocument;
var docName = decodeURI(activeDocument.name).slice(0, -4);

// Define pixels as unit of measurement
var defaultRulerUnits = preferences.rulerUnits;
preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;

// Define variable for the number of layers in the active document
var layerNum = app.activeDocument.artLayers.length;

// Define variable for the active layer in the active document
var layerRef = app.activeDocument.activeLayer;

// Define varibles for x and y of layers
var x = (layerRef.bounds[2].value) - (layerRef.bounds[0].value);
var y = (layerRef.bounds[3].value) - (layerRef.bounds[1].value);
var coords = "";

// Loop to iterate through all layers
function recurseLayers(currLayers) {
  for ( var i = 0; i < currLayers.layers.length; i++ ) {
    layerRef = currLayers.layers[i];
    x = (layerRef.bounds[2].value) - (layerRef.bounds[0].value);
    y = (layerRef.bounds[3].value) - (layerRef.bounds[1].value);
    coords += layerRef.name + ": " + (layerRef.bounds[0].value + x/2) + "x" + "," + (layerRef.bounds[1].value + y/2)  + "y" + "\n";

    //test if it's a layer set
    if ( isLayerSet(currLayers.layers[i]) ) {
      recurseLayers(currLayers.layers[i]);
    }
  }
}

//a test for a layer set
function isLayerSet(layer) {
  try {
    if ( layer.layers.length > 0 ) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  catch(err) {
    return false;
  }
}

// Ask the user for the folder to export to
var FPath = Folder.selectDialog("Save exported coordinates to");

// Detect line feed type
if ( $.os.search(/windows/i) !== -1 ) {
  fileLineFeed = "Windows";
}
else {
  fileLineFeed = "Macintosh";
}

// Export to txt file
function writeFile(info) {
  try {
    var f = new File(FPath + "/" + docName + ".txt");
    f.remove();
    f.open('a');
    f.lineFeed = fileLineFeed;
    f.write(info);
    f.close();
  }
  catch(e){}
}

// Run the functions
recurseLayers(docRef);
preferences.rulerUnits = defaultRulerUnits; // Set preferences back to user 's defaults
writeFile(coords);

// Show results
if ( FPath == null ) {
  alert("Export aborted", "Canceled");
}
else {
  alert("Exported " + docName + " x/y coordinates to " + FPath + "/" + docName + ".txt ");
}
```

Comment: I should add, on the output sample I posted it goes as follows: Root folder, sub folder, layers. There are many root and sub folders in this PSD file, at least 20 root folders, and a variety of subfolders, and around a total of 200 individual layers spread through out.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of other readers facing performance bugs, I've shortened your code up a bit.  This runs fast on my machine.

```
function main() {
    var file = File.saveDialog("Save exported coordinates");
    if (file == null) return;

    if (!file.open('w')) {
        alert("Aborted", "Could not write file.");
        return;
    }

    write(activeDocument.layers, file);
    alert("Exported x/y coordinates to " + file.path);
}

function write(layers, file) {
  for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
    var layer = layers[i];
    var width = layer.bounds[2] - layer.bounds[0];
    var height = layer.bounds[3] - layer.bounds[1];
    file.write(layer.name + ": " + (layer.bounds[0] + width / 2).value + 
        "x, " + (layer.bounds[1] + height / 2).value  + "y\n");

    if (layer instanceof LayerSet) {
      write(layer.layers, file);
    }
  }
}

main();
```